# How to import a utility function that sets cookies into multiple Vue components

Tags: vue.js, vue-cookies

I have several components that I need to check if the user logged on/has valid access token

I currently do check this inside a Vue component method using the contents of isLoggedOut function below. I am thinking that I might need to create an external js file and import this js everywhere that I need to check of credentials. So js function will look sthg like below. However this function also resets the cookies in the component. see this.$cookies. I don't think this is possible due to scoping.

So how can I import functions (like from a utility js file) that also changes this objects? Or is there a better way of what avoiding code duplication in Vue/check for log out in multiple components using same code

```
import axios from "axios";
function isLoggedOut() {
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  const isLoggedOut = True;
  const path = `/user_authentication/protected`;
  axios
    .get(path, { withCredentials: true })
    .then((response) => {
      message = response.data["user"];
      isLoggedOut = false;
      return isLoggedOut;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
      this.$cookies.remove("csrf_access_token");
      isLoggedOut = true;
      return isLoggedOut;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create an `index.ts` file in a folder named `utils` and export the funtion `isLoggedOut`.
2. Pass the Vue app to the function `isLoggedOut` as a prop and call the vue methods.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import axios from "axios";

export function isLoggedOut(app: Vue) {
  axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
  const isLoggedOut = True;
  const path = `/user_authentication/protected`;

  axios
    .get(path, { withCredentials: true })
    .then((response) => {
      message = response.data["user"];
      isLoggedOut = false;
      return isLoggedOut;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);

      app.$cookies.remove("csrf_access_token");

      isLoggedOut = true;
      return isLoggedOut;
    });
}
```

**Component**

```
import { isLoggedOut } from '~/utils'

export default {
  methods: {
    logOut() {
      // Passing the Vue app
      isLoggedOut(this)
    }
  }
}
```